# Method naming and violating single responsibility

Tags: ruby

I need your opinion. Which way do you think is right?

The definition of `message` in this code bothers me because it is a single method that has two separate behaviors.  Depending on how many arguments are passed the method will do different things--that stinks.

On the other hand, calling `message` in the block just feels right. It is subtle. But the difference of assigning the message with or without the `=` seems more significant than it should.  I feel guilty for really wanting to code this way.

Here's a code example:

```
class Queue
    attr_accessor :id

    def initialize(id, &block)
      if block_given?
        instance_eval(&block)
      end
    end

    def message=(value)
        @message = value
    end

    # if no value is given then it reports the value
    def message(value=nil)
        value.nil? ? @message : @message = value
    end
end

Queue.new :test_queue do
    message "This is a test"
end
```

Alternatively, I could use another method for it.

```
set_message "This is a test"
```

This also doesn't have the same effect.

Opinions? Other options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to make your syntax situational. It does seem odd in ruby to collapse your accessor and setter into one method, but you only want that behavior in certain specific situations.

So suppose you have one of these:

```
class AccessorMultiplexer

  def initialize(target)
    @target = target
  end

  def method_missing(method, *args)
    method = "#{method}=" unless args.empty?
    @target.send method, *args
  end

end
```

This doodad can wrap any object, receive a method like `#message`, and invoke either `#message` or `#message=` on the object that it wraps, situationally, based on criteria like "are there arguments?"

So now you can write your Queue with normal getters and setters (freeing you to use `attr_accessor` for your message), and use the multiplexer only when you want that fancy syntax, like in your `initialize` block:

```
class Queue
  attr_accessor :id, :message

  def initialize(id, &block)
    if block_given?
      AccessorMultiplexer.new(self).instance_eval(&block)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This approach is very interesting. I really didn't think to do it this way. But the issue still exists.  If you call `message("this is the message")` do you expect it to assign the message variable?

Comment: Well, in normal Ruby, no I don't think you do. But in your DSL, it does make some sense. And as someone else mentioned, there are precedents for it, like the FactoryGirl DSL, or even the now-obsolete ActionMailer DSL in Rails. Depends on what you're doing, but what I like about this solution is that you get to limit the unusual syntax to the areas where you want it, without polluting your general API.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're building a small [DSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language), in which event `message "Hello"` is analogous to, say, Rails' `belongs_to :user`. The difference is that while `belongs_to` is only, in a sense, a setter (it can't be called without an argument, and doesn't return any useful value), you've built `message` as a getter and a setter.

I think this is about context. In your example:

```
Queue.new :test_queue do
  message "This is a test"
end
```

..the use of `message` feels "right." But in this example, it doesn't:

```
q = Queue.new :test_queue

q.message "This is a test"
```

..at least not as much. `q.message = "..."` makes more sense here.

You could just leave it as-is, i.e. allow assignment both ways, using whichever you prefer and letting others use whichever they prefer. The other option would be to make it work one way inside the constructor block and another way on an instance object. [Here's an article](http://www.themomorohoax.com/2009/02/25/how-to-write-a-clean-ruby-dsl-part-2-line-by-line-with-machinist-rails) that's relevant to this approach, with an apropos shout-out to Factory Girl, which itself contains a great DSL.

Hope that helps!

Comment: it is different than belongs_to but I can see your point from that perceptive.  `message` isn't a class method that defines instance variables.  The block here is used to help build the Queue object.  Much like FactoryGirl (as you pointed out) or EventMachine or Mail.  I think that you answered with that you don't mind if the method does both.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a queue, wouldn't `queueMessage` and `getNextMessage` be more appropriate names for methods?

Comment: I feel that a short name like `message` is more Rubyish. `queueMessage` and `getNextMessage` would be typical for Java.

Comment: IMHO, function names should communicate their purpose in any language. Just because you write Ruby, you shouldn't call a function "disk" if its purpose is "formatDisk", "file" if "deleteFile" etc.

Comment: @Lars-Erik I think that ruby's ability to use '=' in the method definition for `message` is equivalent to using getMessage and setMessage in java. To a ruby programmer get is without and set is with the '='.  So, it seems, like me, you would cringe when message() returns is the getter and message("something") is the setter.  This pattern feels more jQuery-like. I am torn.

Comment: Then it should at least be consistent. If you don't pass it a value, set the private to nothing. Anything else is error prone. So `q.message = "Hello"` and `whatever = q.message()` exclusively, or if you really want to do `q.message("x")` and `q.message(nil)`, set the message to nil in case 2. (Although, I don't get the feeling this is a queue by this example. ;) )